# Displaying Hole Filled image in python with OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, scipy

I am working on some image analysis in python using OpenCV. I want to display an image that I filled in holes with using scipy.ndimage.binary_filled_holes. Upon doing this I could not see anything being displayed when I used cv2.imshow, so I used plt.imshow and saw that the holes in my original image were filled. I want to use the cv2.imshow function to display the image. I did convert the image so that the datatype is uint8, yet still, nothing shows up. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import cv2 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 
import scipy.ndimage

img = cv2.imread('Funky 647.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)   
dst = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(img,None,10,7,21) 
ret, thresh2 = cv2.threshold(dst, 40, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) 
hole_filled= np.uint8(scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes(thresh2))

# plt.imshow(hole_filled)
cv2.imshow('No Holes', hole_filled) 
cv2.waitKey(0)  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hole Filled Image via matplotlib:

[image: Hole Filled Image via matplotlib]

Comment: What happens if you try `cv2.imshow('No Holes', img) `  instead?  i.e. does imshow work at all?

Comment: The read in image displays perfectly. That is what I am confused about. Even when I denoised, and thresholded the image, cv2.imshow worked. Only after using the ndimage function did the image stop displaying. I only see a black screen now.

Comment: When you say 'nothing shows up' do you mean 'nothing' or do you mean ' a window with a black picture shows up'?

Comment: A window with a black picture. Sorry about the ambiguity.

Comment: Your binary filled image may be in the range, 0 to 1. Check the min and max values of it If in the range 0 to 1. Then multiply it by 255, then convert to uint8

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you. Can you explain why do I need to multiply by 255? Also, what is your advice to become better at reading the documentation? When I looked at the scipy documentation for the ndimage function, it was difficult for me to follow. I had to look at examples and still got it wrong.

Comment: @mismatch  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.binary_fill_holes.html shows you what to expect to be returned.  I found what it was by debugging, inspecting 'hole_filled' and seeing what it contained. An array of ones and zeroes is displayed in it's RGB values, i.e. black or very very nearly black compare that to `img` and the problem becomes obvious

Comment: @JeffUK I understand. I see so when you multiply by 255, you are now essentially bringing the white spots back. So when I inputted my array of thresh 2 values into the scipy function, it converted each value of 255 to 1, then looked to see if there were any pixels with a value of 0 surrounded by pixels with a value of 1, and if so converted that pixel of value of zero to one?